# how to select rows in a data frame those are similar on basis of column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

#### My Dataframe is  :

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
'abc' 2    3    4
'asd' 4    5    6
'dfg' 7    5    6
'ghg' 2    3    4
'xyz' 1    3    4
```

Here I want to find the rows( specifically list of 'col1' values) those are similar on the basis of  'col3' and 'col4'
Output :

```
[[asd,dfg],[abc,ghg,xyz]]
```

because here both asd and dfg have similar 'col3' and 'col4' values 3 and 4 respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.groupby` here.

```
df.groupby('col3').col1.apply(list).tolist()
# [['abc', 'ghg', 'xyz'], ['asd', 'dfg']]
```

Comment: @Kaiser Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work -

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('\'','')
df.groupby(['col3'])['col1'].apply(list).reset_index()['col1'].tolist()
[['abc', 'ghg', 'xyz'], ['asd', 'dfg']]
```